# How to select a field from a nested query in junction object

Tags: soql, junction-object

Attached is a small schema of 3 objects in my org

- Opportunity
- custom object: license
- Junction object: opportunity and license

[image]

While I have the oppty id, I need to get ALL licenses that are related to it, and for each of them, trying get a certain custom field: dongle_id__c

Following single queries work: 
Get ID's of licenses that are related to oppty (in the nested sql):

```
SELECT Id,
(Select OfLicense__c FROM Opportunities_and_Licenses__r)
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006M00000086xpw'
```

The first nested query : `Select OfLicense__c FROM Opportunities_and_Licenses__r` gives me the licenses ID's, and for each, I want to grab the Dongle_id__c value

Tried several variations neither work:

The following SQL - returns me the needed data:

```
select dongle_id__c from OptiTex_License__c where id in (Select OfLicense__c FROM Opportunity_and_License__c WHERE ofopportunity__c ='006M00000086xpw')
```

But trying to insert that, as the nested SQL returns me a relationship error on the `OptiTex_License__c` .

```
SELECT Id,
(select dongle_id__c from OptiTex_License__c where id in (Select OfLicense__c FROM Opportunity_and_License__c WHERE ofopportunity__c ='006M00000086xpw'))
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006M00000086xpw'
```

- Also tried to remove the inner/nested: WHERE clause:

  SELECT Id,
  (select dongle_id__c from OptiTex_License__c where id in (Select OfLicense__c FROM Opportunity_and_License__c))
  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006M00000086xpw'

I tried to remove the "Where id in...." and change the `Opportunity_and_License__c` to it's relationship name

```
(select dongle_id__c from Opportunities_and_Licenses__r)
```

That gives me error the Dongle_id__c is "No Such column" on the junction object - correct - it's on the related one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that a single junction object points to a single license, then you should be able to follow that relationship in the sub query, e.g.

```
SELECT Id,
(Select OfLicense__r.dongle_id__c FROM Opportunities_and_Licenses__r)
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = '006M00000086xpw'
```

Answer (score 4):

With these association objects it usually works best to query the association object. You can then go up the parent relationships one or more levels (up to 5):

```
Set<Id> dongleIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunities_and_Licenses__c ol : [
        select OfLicense__r.Dongle_id__c
        from Opportunities_and_Licenses__c
        where OfOpportunity__r.Id = '006M00000086xpw'
        and OfLicense__r.Dongle_id__c != null
        ]) {
    dongleIds.add(ol.OfLicense__r.Dongle_id__c);
}
```

**PS** Just saw mast0r's comment - it is the same as that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately (or not?) it is **only one** level that can be cpecified in the query:

> In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child
>   relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM
>   clause specifies Account, the SELECT clause can only specify the
>   Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child
>   object of Contact.

[Relationship Queries: Understanding Relationship Query Limitations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#relate_query_limits).

When you try to execute such query like

```
Select Id, (Select Id, (Select Status From Tasks) From Cases) From Account
```

you will get the error:

[image]

Comment: so no matter my wishes, I will need to add a query within the for loop that I have?

Comment: I think you can do it just in one query. As a target object i would take **Opportunities and Licenses** because it have  relationsships to other two objects: `Select Id, OptiTex_License__r.dongle_id__c
From Opportunities_and_Licenses__c
Where ofopportunity__c = 'XXXX'`